# PyMysql на запрос отвечает фигурными скобками

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

При запросе

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user_id = %s' % (vk_id)
  c.execute(sql)
  result = c.fetchall()
  #print(result)

  for x in result:
    print(x)
```

Выдает ответ

```
{'id': 1, 'user_id': 454267478, 'avokado': 142234, 'gold': 0}
```

В фигурных скобках. Вопрос почему, ведь во всех примерах в интернете все возвращается списком в круглых скобках

Comment: Вот будь у тебя несколько записей - были бы они в квадратных скобках. Причём каждая отдельная - в фигурных. А коли запись одна - так зачем для неё массив городить?

Answer (score 0):

Похоже при создании соединения у вас указан `DictCursor` наподобие:

```
connection = pymysql.connect(..., cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
# ----------------------------------------------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^
```

В этом случае курсор будет возвращать строки как словари с именами столбцов в качестве ключей.